# C# program gets stuck as soon as I run it for some reason (blank command line)

Tags: c#, loops, cmd

I've wrote a simple C# program that for some reason won't print the first line in main.
All 4 other projects in the same solution run without a problem.
Maybe it will help if I mention that one project from the solution is being referenced in this project that is not running.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Basic_Sand_Clock;

namespace Advanced_Sand_Clock
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sdsd");

      //  string advancedSandClock = GenerateAdvancedSandClock(9);
      //  Console.WriteLine(advancedSandClock);
      //  Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static uint GetValidInput()
    {
        string stringInput = "";
        uint sandClockHeight = 0;

        while (stringInput.Equals(""))
        {
            stringInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!uint.TryParse(stringInput, out sandClockHeight))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive number");
                stringInput = "";
            }
        }
        return sandClockHeight;
    }

    private static string GenerateAdvancedSandClock(uint height)
    {
        if (height % 2 == 0)
        {
            height++;
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sandClock = Basic_Sand_Clock.Program.GenerateSandClockWithInput(stringBuilder, height);

        return sandClock.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

What i get:[image]

Another screen shot with solution explorer:
[image]

Comment: And when you debugged line by line you found out...?

Comment: Did you already try to wait a few seconds? It's possible that the debugger needs some time to attach

Comment: Make sure that in the project properties your [startup object](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/479467/Startup_object.jpg) property points to the `Program.Main` method as intended.

Comment: Did you set this project as startup project and select the correct object? Did you try to put a breakpoint on the first expected line?

Comment: Take a screenshot of the solution explorer for this solution and show us that.

Comment: Given you have 4 tabs open - each called Program.cs, I'd say your not running the expected project or entry point - Main.  Press F11 (when your not running) to start debugging and hit the first line of the program.

Comment: It is the correct project. Startup project is set correctly, break point is simply being overseen. If I wait a couple of seconds before closing the program will be stuck. added another screenshot